# Function or Variable in Where Statement?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there a way to put a function or variable in the first value of a where statement?

For example,

```
$equipments=DB::table('equipments')
            ->leftjoin('orders', function ($join) {
                $join->on('orders.equipment_id', '=', 'equipments.equipmentID')
                    ->where('orders.orderUser_id','=', Auth::user()->id);
            })
            ->leftjoin('business_users', 'business_users.id', '=' , 'equipments.user_id')
            ->where('equipments.equipmentArchived','=','0')
            *->where($this->countOrders('equipments.equipmentID'),'<','1')*
            ->orderBy('equipments.equipmentListedDate','DESC')
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(10);
```

The count orders function is

```
public static function countOrders($id)
    {
        //
        $members=DB::table('orders')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.orderUser_id')
            ->leftjoin('equipments', 'equipments.equipmentID', '=', 'orders.equipment_id')
            ->where('orders.equipment_id','=', $id)
            ->where('orders.status','=','ACCEPTED')
            ->count();

        return $members;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-methods)" method to do that.

```
$equipments = DB::table('equipments')
    ->leftjoin('orders', function ($join) {
        $join->on('orders.equipment_id', '=', 'equipments.equipmentID')
            ->where('orders.orderUser_id','=', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->leftjoin('business_users', 'business_users.id', '=' , 'equipments.user_id')
    ->where('equipments.equipmentArchived','=','0')
    ->whereRaw('? < ?', [$this->countOrders('equipments.equipmentID'), 1])
    ->orderBy('equipments.equipmentListedDate','DESC')
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It's still outputting the equipment, despite having a value of 1 when I print out the result of the function in the view. Maybe the function in the whereRaw isn't actually printing a number, or something else, :/

Comment: I tested by inputting just random ids into the function parameter, and it seems to work, but when run with equipments.equipmentID, it outputs everything, even the ids that I worked on my test